# TensorFlow Census Example - get predictions

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm following the census classification example for TensorFlow:

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide

and have a trained model via:

```
m.train(
input_fn=input_fn(df_train,train_labels, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True),
steps=2000)
```

I would like two further things:

1) In the evaluation to get back each row of the census with the prediction for that row
2) To use the trained model to get a prediction for a given row(s) of census data.

Comment: Have you tried to use the [`tf.estimator.Estimator.predict()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#predict) method to do this (i.e. `m.predict(...)`)? It is the main interface for getting predictions from a trained model.